# Packaging and Reusing VBA Code in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

So I use Excel 2007 .xltm templates with data connections to SQL Server to pull report tables.  Each file has a handful of VBA functions to manage refreshing, disconnecting, formatting, user input, etc.  I have 50+ .xltms with the same set of modules, so its quite cumbersome to make changes to all their VBA.

Is it possible to code the excel VBA to reference outside VBA files?  That way, when I make a change, I only change it in the main vba source file.  This might be a stretch, but is it possible to write a module/.NET dll that would import the .bas file on open?

Thanks in advance,
-Matt

Comment: Do you need the code to be incorporated into each template, or could it all just reside in an add-in which gets loaded on open?

Comment: An add-in could work. The templates would only call the functions from the add-in, correct? Do they require a more coding know-how than just VBA? Ive briefly read up on COM add-ins for excel.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty straightforward: http://www.exceltip.com/st/How_to_Use_Your_Excel_Add-In_Functions_in_VBA/630.html   You just need to make sure that any code in the add-in isn't referring (eg) to "ThisWorkbook" but instead uses "ActiveWorkbook", etc.

Comment: Tim, you should post that as an answer so you can get credit and so that other users can find the solution if they are having the same issue as the OP. :)

Comment: Yes, please do. This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks Tim.

Comment: Broken link for me, consider [this instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10001620/1175496)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) in his comment.