# VBA code import

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA project I am doing in excel. I will have many workbooks that will use the same code and I do not want to have to copy the code to all the workbooks if I make a change. Is there anyway to have the code in one central place and then have all the workbooks access that code?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047467/packaging-and-reusing-vba-code-in-excel

Comment: I suspect solution 1 from Siddharth's answer will be your best option.  However, [this recent answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9864075/973283) shows how to run macros in one workbook against other workbooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have two options

**1)** Copy and paste the code in the Personal workbook.

More details here

**Topic: Deploy your Excel macros from a central file**

**Link**: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/deploy-your-excel-macros-from-a-central-file-HA001087296.aspx

**2)** Create an Add-In

Mode details here

**Topic: Creating An XLA Add-In For Excel**

**Link**: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/createaddin.aspx

*Note*: You can create Add-In in VBA as well as Visual Studio. For COM Add-Ins (created using Visual Studio), please refer to this link.

**Topic: Office Development with Visual Studio (VSTO)**

**Link**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430

HTH

Sid

Comment: Siddharth, thanks for the suggestions, I don't think option one would work, as these workbooks will be used by multiple users. They are stored on a networked location and accessed by many different people. So from my understanding using my personal workbook would not solve the problem. Perhaps the Add-in is the better option. Another idea I had is to use a library. I am worried about updating code though. If I make a change to a library will it be changed in all the workbooks that reference it?

Comment: Looks like I was a bit quick to respond, I played around a bit with the XLA add-ins. Looks like that could be the solution. Its too bad I don't have VSTO, I think that would be much better.